# SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, case

I am trying to make a categorization is SQL Server 2012 (View [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/04779/1) demo)

However, when I introduce the subquery it retrieves me the following message: "*Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression*"

What script should I use instead?

Edit: I would like to have the following output, based on the SQL Fiddle demo:

```
CATEGORY    REGION    PRECIO    CATEGORY
Pepe         Paris      21        Other
Pizza        Paris      21        Pizza
Pizza        Paris      22        Pizza
Salad        Paris      22        Other
Beverage    Vidreres    20       Beverage   
Beverage    Vidreres    24       Beverage   
Pizza       Vidreres    19        Pizza
Pizza       Vidreres    20        Pizza
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your desired output based on your example records?

Comment: I'm going to add it now

Comment: Just checked your query seems incorrect. What output you are expecting?

Comment: Are you using GROUP BY on purpose? Since you're grouping by every column in the table, it's hard to understand what it accomplishes.

Comment: I am just using group by because SQL Fiddle required me to do so (Maybe it happened at some time when I was trying to figure out the script)

Comment: Can you please update the output based on your additional requirement that you have a count? Count of WHAT? Also can you make the expected output match the SQL fiddle data? There is at least one row missing (in the pizza category). Sloppy, incomplete questions lead to sloppy, incomplete answers.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the count (please stop changing requirements). To avoid repeating code, you can perform the `CASE` expression in a CTE (you could also use a derived table).

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT Category, Region, Precio, 
    Products = CASE WHEN Category IN ('Pizza','Beverage')
      THEN Category ELSE 'Other' END
  FROM dbo.supportContacts
)
SELECT Category, Region, Precio, Products,
  ProductCount = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Products)
FROM x;
```

[SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/04779/30)

Comment: is your ProductCount values are Correct..?

Comment: @Pandian I have no idea what the OP's requirements are; do you know? I assumed he wants the count of each category (the derived column using the CASE expression), not the individual products.

Comment: @Pandian maybe, but I'm not really interested in guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
SELECT *, case
            when Category = 'Pizza' then 'Pizza'
            when Category = 'Beverage' then 'Beverage'
            else 'Other' end as Products

 FROM supportContacts
Group by Region, Category, Precio
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need subqueries for that

```
SELECT *, case
      when Category = 'Pizza' then 'Pizza'
          when Category = 'Beverage' then 'Beverage'
       else 'Other' end as Products
 FROM supportContacts
Group by Region, Category, Precio
```

Output:

```
| CATEGORY |   REGION | PRECIO | PRODUCTS |
-------------------------------------------
|     Pepe |    Paris |     21 |    Other |
|    Pizza |    Paris |     21 |    Pizza |
|    Pizza |    Paris |     22 |    Pizza |
|    Salad |    Paris |     22 |    Other |
| Beverage | Vidreres |     20 | Beverage |
| Beverage | Vidreres |     24 | Beverage |
|    Pizza | Vidreres |     19 |    Pizza |
|    Pizza | Vidreres |     20 |    Pizza |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/04779/9)**

Comment: Additionally, what should I introduce to count the number of products. I mean, I'd like to introduce another column with count(Products), but it doesn't allow me to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you write that query to get the Below result...

[image]

If i got you then try the below Query..

```
Select Category, Region, Precio,Products,count(Products) _Count from
(Select Category, Region, Precio,
case
        when Category = 'Pizza' then 'Pizza'
        when Category = 'Beverage' then 'Beverage'
        else 'Other' 
end as Products 
FROM supportContacts) res
Group by Category,Region,Precio,Products
```